# CSS Dropdown Menu with Images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a dropdown menu based on the 4 pics you see in this picture --> http://www.potmetnoten.nl/images/dropdown.png 
I am trying to achieve the following:

- Initially only show the first pic.
- When hovering over first pic --> Show other pics.

I have tried all sorts of things with display and with visible, neither of them work. When I hover over the first pic (li) nothing happens.

Does any of you see what I'm missing? Thanks a lot in advance.

```css
    ul {

      list-style: none;

      width: 200px;

      height: 170px;

      padding-left: 30px;

      margin: 0px;

      border: none;

      float: left;

      margin-right: 5px;

      position: relative;

      z-index: 1;

    }

    li[data-type="noten"] {

      background-image: url(images/menu-noten.jpg);

      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      display: block;

    }

    li[data-type="pitten"] {

      background-image: url(images/menu-pitten.png);

      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      display: none;

    }

    li[data-type="muesli"] {

      background-image: url(images/menu-muesli.png);

      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      display: none

    }

    li[data-type="fruit"] {

      background-image: url(images/menu-fruit.png);

      background-repeat: no-repeat;

      display: none;

    }

    li:hover li {

      display: block;

      /* display the dropdown */

    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-type="noten"></li>
  <li data-type="pitten"></li>
  <li data-type="muesli"></li>
  <li data-type="fruit"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a hover code for the first element in the Ordered List (ul), so whenever you hover over the the first element "Picture", the others should appear.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="noten"  ></li>
<li class="pitten" ></li>
<li class="muesli" ></li>
<li class="fruit" ></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {

  list-style: none;

  width: 200px;

  height: 170px;

  padding-left: 30px;

  margin: 0px;

  border: none;

  float: left;

  margin-right: 5px;

  position: relative;

  z-index: 1;

}


li .noten {

  background-image: url(images/menu-noten.jpg);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  display: block;

}

li .pitten {

  background-image: url(images/menu-pitten.png);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  display: none;

}

li .muesli {

  background-image: url(images/menu-muesli.png);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  display: none

}

li .fruit {

  background-image: url(images/menu-fruit.png);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  display: none;

}

li .notten:hover {

  display: block;

  /* display the dropdown */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li[data-type="noten"]:hover li
```

if it doesn't work give your li[data-type="noten"] a class, say *class=first*
and try

```
li:first:hover li {}
```

else try:

```
ul:hover li{}
```

Also: you are forcing a specific height on the parent (ul) you shouldn't do that let the parent always take the total height of all children sitting in a list one after the other

Comment: ul:hover li{} is completely wrong, because he must specify which element should the hover be applied on.

Comment: Well then he should specfy using the child notation using: ul:hover > li

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this, using the `:hover + #id` method:

```css
ul {

      list-style: none;
      display:inline-block;

}

img {
  
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  
  }

li#pitten {
  
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  
  }

#noten:hover + li#pitten {
  
  opacity:1;
  
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="noten"><img id="noten" src="images/menu-noten.jpg"></li>
  <li id="pitten"><img id="pitten" src="images/menu-pitten.jpg"><img id="muesli" src="images/menu-muesli.jpg"><img id="fruit" src="images/menu-fruit.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Now I am trying to keep the menu items showing when I move my cursor over the lower 3 items. Any idea how to do this? :hover doesn't seem to work for the <li> containing the three other images.